# Syntax error: redirection unexpected netcat busybox

Tags: linux, scripting, netcat, busybox

I'm new to netcat and trying to use the same line in the busybox as i do in my pc.

I want to know how I can change the redirection operator.

```
nc -w 30 IP 3031 -e <<<"info"
```

this is the error

```
-sh: syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

I think it doesn't like <<<, but what should I change it to?

btw this script throws the information it gets to the screen, by sending "info"

Comment: `sh` doesn't support [here strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings).

Comment: Many thanks, i found the answer in wikipedia , just changed to: echo "info" | nc - w 30 IP 3031

Comment: Good that you found the solution.  Now answer your own question.

Comment: i need to wait 7 hours :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change to:

```
echo "info" | nc - w 30 IP 3031
```